# Java equvalent of VB.NET "With" statement while initializing a class

Tags: java, vb.net

Is there a java equvalent of VB.NET's `With` statement while constructing a class like this:

```
Dim newVar As New MyClass With {.var1 = "Hello", .var2 = "World"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't, you'd have to do something like this with a constructor.

```
class MyClass{

  public String var1, var2;

  public MyClass(String str1, String str2){
    var1 = str1;
    var2 = str2;
  }

}
```

And instantiate it with:

```
MyClass newVar = new MyClass("Hello", "World");
```

If you don't want to use a constructor but still want to declare the variable on one line, you could do something like the following:

```
class MyClass{

  public String var1, var2;

  public MyClass setVar1(String str){
    var1 = str;
    return this;
  }

  public MyClass setVar2(String str){
    var2 = str;
    return this;
  }

}
```

And then declare the variable like so:

```
MyClass newVar = (new MyClass()).setVar1("Hello").setVar2("World");
```